# DataGridView editable cell input overwritten when another cell is updated

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, datagrid

I have a `DataGridView` bound through a `BindingSource` to a `DataTable`, and my grid has editable columns where the user inputs the value, and also some read-only columns that are programmatically updated in real time (think like a stock ticker).  For the programmatically updated columns I am updating the value in the `DataTable` and then the value in the DataGridView is updated because of the databinding.
The issue I'm having is that while a user is editing one cell, if another cell is updated programmatically then the text the user has inputted in the first cell gets overwritten (reset to the cell's value before it was edited).

This doesn't seem like an unusual situation to me, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.  Anyone know what I might be doing wrong, or can point me towards an example that shows how to do this properly?

Comment: The programmatic updated columns, does this happens in a timer or how ? I think you need to disable the programmatically updates while the user is editing, since it looks like it updates the entire record and thus resets whatever the user was typing. You might consider not using binding to populate your datagridview, but do it all yourself, that way you can control which cells are changed by the programmatic updates and which are not.

Comment: I didn't develop that part of the system, but I believe there is a background thread that is constantly waiting to receive PUSH updates from the PUSH server, then when it receives an update it invokes a method on the UI thread to update the appropriate DataTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I worked it out so I'll add my solution here in case it will be helpful to someone else.

I handled the `CellBeginEdit`, `CellEndEdit` and `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` events of the `DataGridView` and added the following code:

```
private void Grid_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    ((DataRowView)((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).BeginEdit();
}

private void Grid_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // need this check for when the program is closed while a cell is in edit mode
    // otherwise an IndexOutOfRangeException occurs
    if (((BindingSource)((DataGridView)sender).DataSource).List.Count > e.RowIndex)
        ((DataRowView)((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).EndEdit();
}

private void Grid_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // commit changes to the table as soon as they are entered so they don't 
    // get overwritten when the DataTable is updated
    if (Grid.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        Grid.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}
```

I also found that the Esc key functionality of the `DataGridView` was reverting not only the changes to the cell currently in edit mode, but also the changes where values were set directly in the `DataTable` (the real time programmatic updates), so I overrode the Esc key functionality for the `DataGridView` as follows:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (CurrentCell != null && CurrentCell.IsInEditMode)
    {
        if (keyData == (Keys.Escape))
        {
            CurrentCell.Value = valueBeforeEdit;
            EditingControl.Text = valueBeforeEdit.ToString();
            EndEdit();

            return true;
        }
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

where `valueBeforeEdit` holds the value of the cell before editing (set in the `DataGridView`'s `CellBeginEdit` event handler).

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when the underlying value in the `DataTable` changes, the `DataGridView.DataBindingComplete` event gets fired - resetting the bindings.

[My first suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35277366/1) was that you capture this event and just check if the `EditedFormattedValue` for the `CurrentCell` was different than the `Value` - if so, then set the `Value`. This worked - until I checked for the first row - which completely ignored my logic.

The only solution I could find to always work was to change how the programmatic real-time updates happened. If possible, instead of updating the `DataTable` columns, just update the `DataGridView` columns. These changes will perpetuate to the source but binding will not reset - thus your current editing cell will not lose any changes.

```
foreach (DataRow row in this.table.Rows)
{
    row[1] = someNewValue;
}
```

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    row.Cells[1].Value = someNewValue;
}
```

Comment: I tried out your suggestion, but for some reason DataGridView.DataBindingComplete doesn't always fire.  Sometimes it fires as expected, but sometimes even though I can see the value changing on the screen it never runs my DataBindingComplete handler...

Comment: That was my former suggestion before I learned a flaw in my solution using DataBindingComplete.  Instead, if possible, just change the way you are doing the programmatic update of your read-only columns to my suggestion (I.E. set the DataGridViewCell value instead of the underlying DataTable cell value).

Comment: Unfortunately setting the DataGridViewCell value is not possible as the programmatically updated columns are updated in the background directly on the DataTable, with the changes propagated to the DataGridView through the data binding.

Comment: Ah, that is unfortunate. My prior solution nearly worked for that case except the first row refused to work - and the other cells of the row containing the editing cell wouldn't update until you finished editing the current cell. I'll keep looking into it when I have more free time.